# How do I find the average velocity within a time interval

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity

A particle moves in one dimension, and its position as a function of time is given by 
x = (1.8 m/s)t + (−3.6 m/s2)t2.
(a) What is the particle's average velocity from t = 0.45 s to t = 0.55 s? 
(b) What is the particle's average velocity from t = 0.49 s to t = 0.51 s? 
I understand the basic formula for finding average velocity. My problem is that I get very confused with the m/s2 and how to multiply by the t = 0.45 s, when trying to find the initial position and final position.

Comment: Calculate the position at the start and end of each interval. The $m/s^2$ is multiplied by $t^2$ so the units are still in meters, as they should be... For example, the position $x$ at time t=0.45 s is given by 1.8*0.45 - 3.6 * 0.45 * 0.45

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

The expression $x = (1.8 \;\text{m/s})t + (−3.6 \;\text{m/s}^2)t^2$ is written like that to alert you to use seconds for the unit of time.  If you do that then each of the terms on the right-hand side of the equation will be in metres and that will also be the unit for the position $x$.

So you are dealing with a relationship between position $x$ in metres and time $t$ in seconds.

$x = 1.8 t −3.6 t^2$

which as a graph looks like this

[image]

I include this to warn you that during the time intervals which have been chosen the position changes from positive to negative so you must be careful with the signs when using the expression

$\text{average velocity} = \dfrac{\text{final position - initial position} }{\text{final time - initial time}}$